# first-of-type selector doesn't work for div elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Clarify me if this is a bug or my understanding is poor.

I am trying to apply *first-of-type* selector to a group of div and p tags and found it behaves differently for each of them. It selects only the *.form__group* class of *div* tag and not *p* tag

```css
/* css */

.form__group:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
.form__group:first-of-type span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- form__group class for p tag -->

<form class="form">
  <p class="form__message">test</p>
  <p class="form__group">
    <span>The first paragraph.</span>
  </p>
  <p class="form__group">The second paragraph.</p>
</form>

<!-- form__group class for div tag -->
<form class="form">
  <p class="form__message">test</p>
  <div class="form__group">
    <span>The fourth paragraph.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form__group">The fifth paragraph.</div>
</form>
```

Please look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sabarigr/52vu5dks/

Answer (score 5):

That is because `p` with class `form__group` is not first `p` in form its `p` with class `form__message`. You can see here that if you remove first `p.form__message` it will select `p.form__group` because in that case that is first element of type `p`

```css
.form__group:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}

.form__group:first-of-type span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- form__group class for p tag -->
<form class="form">
  <p class="form__group"><span>The first paragraph.</span></p>
  <p class="form__group">The second paragraph.</p>
</form>

<!-- form__group class for div tag -->
<form class="form">
  <p class="form__message">test</p>
  <div class="form__group"><span>The fourth paragraph.</span></div>
  <div class="form__group">The fifth paragraph.</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the concept now. What I was trying to achieve was similar to having `:first-of-class` pseudo class, which I reckon isn't available right now.

Comment: You're welcome, yes there is no such selector in css yet.